# Running XVnc on multi-platform hudson slaves

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I'm in the process of transitioning the Eclipse project build to run on Hudson. We run 64,000 JUnit tests on Windows, Linux and Mac each build.  For Linux and Mac, we use the Xvnc plugin for ui tests.  The Xvnc binaries on the Mac are in a different location than they are on Linux. However, there isn't an option on the Hudson master to specify a different location for the binaries on different slaves. Has anyone else overcome this problem?  How do you run UI tests on a Mac Hudson slave?

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329830

Answer (score 3):

Okay so it's lame to answer your own question, but I hope this can avoid some pain for people running Mac Hudson slaves.

We installed http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/ as the vnc daemon on the Mac Hudson slave.

Specifying different vnc binary paths on a per slave basis is an known limitation of hudson.  You can only specify one in the master's configuration.

If you make a soft link on the mac slave from /Library/StartupItems/OSXvnc/OSXvnc-server to the name of the vnc binary that the master hudson is configured to expect, Xvnc starts on the Mac slave. And our UI tests run successfully.